# get lines where value does not exist

Tags: python

I'm trying to get from 2D list the lines where value = 2 does not exists:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 0, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I've been using:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
   if list[i] in [list]:
      # dot stuff
```

the problem here is that evrytime the code is using the actual line which is list[i] and ignore the the rest  even if 2 does not exists on it

hope Iwas clear

Thank you

Comment: dont use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: List comprehension offers a shorter syntax when you want to create a new list based on the values of an existing list.

Comment: thank you balderman actualy the name is BineroGrid, here i'v named it list to show that's it's a list type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like the below

```
lst = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]]
lst = [x for x in lst if 2 not in x]
print(lst)
```

output

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this your expected output?

```
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

This is the working code:

```
a = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 0, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 0]]
 
for i in range(len(a)):
   if 2 not in a[i]:
       print(a[i])
```